# Firejail not hiding files with Brave browser

Tags: firejail

If I run the following:

```
firejail brave-browser
```

And then try and access files in the browser (such as when uploading a file), Brave still has access to my entire home folder.

Usually this doesn't happen with Firejail. I've tried it with Firefox, and it only gives access to the `~/Downloads` folder.

I've verified Firejail is running with `firejail --list`:

```
18974:daniel::firejail /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
```

So I'm not sure what the problem is. The exact same command works with Firefox, so why isn't it hiding files with Brave?

### Environment

- OS: Pop!_OS 21.04
- GNOME version: 3.38.5
- Brave browser: v1.29.81 (installed with `apt`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firejail not hiding files with Brave browser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671071/firejail-not-hiding-files-with-brave-browser)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question was cross-posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671071/firejail-not-hiding-files-with-brave-browser) and on AskUbuntu, and this is the instance on AskUbuntu that was migrated to U&L SE.